# Bootstrap toggle checkbox doesn't get sent with request

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.1

I have a checkbox on my Laravel 5.1 form that I have incorporated the Bootstrap Toggle attributes to. The problem is, when the form is submitted, the checkbox doesn't get sent with the request. I have verified that it is selected (checked = checked). I have another checkbox on the same form that isn't using the Bootstrap Toggle styling and it passes as expected.

Here is the form input:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('status', '1', $employee->status, array('data-toggle' => 'toggle')) !!}
```

($employee->status is a boolean)

Here are all of the scripts and css I'm loading in my project:

```
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/pams.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet">

@yield('head-css')

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
{{-- Twitter Bootstrap --}}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{{-- This is for the converting a checkbox to a sliding toggle --}}
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
{{-- This is for the autocomplete in the select boxes --}}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
{{-- This is for adding photos through drag and drop or click --}}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
```

If I remove "data-toggle" => "toggle" it works as expected.

Comment: Where is the form? some part of your code might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem, I created laravel page with form (boostrap, dropzone and this bootstrap toggle included and active):

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'test')) !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('status', '1', true, array('data-toggle' => 'toggle')) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Send') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And I ran this code on Chrome and Mozilla, the results were:
If I have selected the checkbox (on), the **status=1** has been added to the form request (the sniffer is Charles)

[image: form checkbox selected]

But if I click once again to make it off, nothing has been added to the form request. And this is normal, you can simple confirm it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked)

Maybe the problem is in select2 library, but I do not know what are you doing with this. Rest of your code would be really useful to help you.